# Using POLYMORPHIC and :THROUGH association at the same time in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller

I am having a hard time with more advanced association in Rails.

Here is what I want to do:

- landlord can create many properties, and they all belongs to the a landlord
- each property can have many tenants, and each tenants can only belong to one property.
- the land lord should be able to able to use CRUD on new tenants in each of his respective property.
- the tenants can only see attributes/status related to their own property

Here is what I think how it should be laid out

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tenant, polymorphic: true
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, as: :tenant
  belongs_to :landlords

end

class Landlord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :property
  has_many :users, as: :tenant, through: :properties

end
```

Is this correct?

Is it better/less convoluted without the polymorphic association, and just use the through association?

Comment: Where does the User class come in to play? Should User be Tenant?

Comment: because it is an polymorphic association, tenant is an interface setup, and User is the model that belongs to the tenant interface. that is my understanding, I am still quite new at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
class Landlord 
  has_many :properties
  has_many :tenants, through: :properties
end 

class Tenant
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :landlord, through: :properties
end

class Property
  belongs_to :landlord
  has_many :tenants
end
```

See this [active record associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for more information.

Comment: I see! I can have additional attributes attached to properties? I mean, it is not just a join table right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is a join table; however, it can still have other attributes. For example - the property could have :bedrooms, :bathrooms, :price_per_month, etc...